# Seeing All Icons on the Menu Bar

Tags: macos, menu-bar, microsoft

I currently have the following icons on the status bar. However, I have other applications running, specifically OneDrive, which I believe it is supposed to show an icon.

[image]

Does the status bar show all icons (of the apps running that would choose to have one) by default? If not, is there any way to either force it to show all icons or choose which ones to show?

I have tried re-running OneDrive and I confident it used to have one. I can see it running on my activity monitor, but I don't see the icon anymore (even after restarting the computer)

Comment: Where would the icon go there appears to be no space - I think the app's menus are done first then fill from the right - you'll have to use apps with less in the menu

Comment: I am also looking for a solution to that (13" MBP). Some application/way to reduce the font size of the menubar item or their spacing would probably be ideal...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[AccessMenuBar](http://www.ortisoft.de/en/accessmenubarapps/) solves that problem.

Comment: Wow, wished I installed this years ago. The sound and video effects are a bit annoying, but can fortunately be switched off.

Comment: this app is what I need!

Comment: unfortunately it crashes on my mac with Apple chip and OS 13.0.1

Answer (score 21):

- Finder has a relatively short app menu, so activating Finder is a quick way to see more menu bar icons.  (And the built-in Maps app has an even shorter app menu.)
- [Bartender](http://www.macbartender.com/) collapses the menu bar items into a submenu, which will let you see more of them (without being hidden by app menus).

[image]

Comment: +1 for using Finder!  Solved my problem with no new software to add..

Answer (score 10):

App menus take precedence over menu bar items. In this case, whatever your foreground app is, it's menu options are too long, causing Window and Help to hide the menu bar items that would otherwise occupy that space. To see more menu bar items, use an app with a shorter menu list, or increase your screen resolution.

Comment: Thanks. That's quite unfortunate. I am using a vertical orientation on [my display](http://www.samsung.com/us/business/displays/monitors/LS24C45KBWV/GO) which has a `1900 x 1200` resolution (`1200 x 1900` in vertical). This isn't something I can change. I was hoping I would be able to make the status bar multi-row or that there would be at a minimum some way of scrolling through them, but I take that this is not currently possible?

Comment: @user I use and recommend Bartender for menu bar item management. You can also remove system menu bar items to free some space; for example if you don't change the language often, or don't use Time Machine, you can command-drag the items off the bar to remove them, leaving more space for other apps' items.

Answer (score 4):

As others have explained the menu space is limited.

But you may not need a couple of the ones you have in there so you could try and remove them to see if that gives you the room.

**ExpressCard** ,**Timemachine**, **Bluetooth**,**Keyboard input**.

Since they are Menu Extras  you can hold down the <kbd>cmd</kbd>  key, click each menu item and drag away from the menu bar and release them to puff away.

Or use the items preferences to do the same.( not sure the ExpressCard has one)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use [BetterTouchTool](https://www.boastr.net) for that purpose. For example:
[image]

Comment: Nice. Didn't know that was in BTT.